# How to SWAP rows in Python data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried all ways mentioned on this topic in site, but nothing is working.

I just need to swap 2 rows available in CSV file. mentioned below
I have tried with these options also not working.
Just pasting more code for better understaing..I am taking row 2 and 3 from Questionnaire.csv and putting in file Questionnaire_edit.csv. now After that I need to swap in rows in new file.

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip
import csv
app = Flask(__name__)
df = pd.read_csv("Questionnaire.csv")
df1 = df.iloc[1:2]
df1 = df1[::-1]
df1.to_csv('Questionnaire_edit.csv', index = False)
```

All suggestion code like df1 = df1.loc[[2,1]] or re-index is working only when CSV has index row like showing below.

INPUT value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iskq2.png)

Expected Output Value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jlot.png)

Code is working if CSV has in this format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAeS4.png)

Comment: try using `df[::-1]` to invert the whole frame

Comment: Ty Chris, but seems this is also not working. I am editing question to give more input may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `loc` and the corresponding index of rows that you want to swap.

```
df.loc[[2, 1]]
```

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

outputs

```
    0   1   2
----------------
0 | 1   2   3
1 | 4   5   6
```

To swap index 0 and 1, do

```
df.loc[[1, 0]]
```

outputs

```
    0   1   2
--------------
1 | 4   5   6
0 | 1   2   3
```

Comment: Did the change df1 = df.loc[1,0] as there are only 2 rows
getting error "TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>"

Comment: not `df1 = df.loc[1,0]` it would be `df1 = df.loc[[1,0]]`

Comment: In your case, it would be `df1 = df.loc[[2, 1]]`

Comment: Ty Soumik, the suggested code is working only when CSV have header row (Index row) . it is not working if CSV file has only 2 rows. mentioning the pic in question

Answer (score 1):

Use `reindex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, -1), columns=[*'ABCDE'])

df.reindex([4,2,1,3])
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
4  20  21  22  23  24
2  10  11  12  13  14
1   5   6   7   8   9
3  15  16  17  18  19
```

You can even duplicate rows with reindex:

```
df.reindex([1]*2+[0,4]+[3]*3)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1   5   6   7   8   9
1   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   1   2   3   4
4  20  21  22  23  24
3  15  16  17  18  19
3  15  16  17  18  19
3  15  16  17  18  19
```

Comment: Ty Scott for quick suggestion, seems this is also not working did the same below. Also i have 868 columns in CSV file. 

import pandas as pd
import csv
app = Flask(__name__)
df = pd.read_csv("Questionnaire.csv")
df1 = df.iloc[1:2]
#df1 = df1[::-1]
df1 = df1.reindex([1,0])
df1.to_csv('Contact Tracing Questionnaire_edit.csv', index = False)
print(df1)

Comment: @Vikas Try using `header=None` like this:  `df=read_csv("Questionnaire.csv", headers=None)` then `df1=....`